One WebPart not showing up in workbench while another shows up ok
I'm new to SPFX, and I'm trying to create a couple of web parts.  I downloaded the Contoso Retail Demo and have basically cannibalised it to create what I need.  The demo had multiple web parts in one project, so I assumed I could do the same, but I must be missing something - one web part shows up in the gallery and the other doesn't.
I can get each web part to show individually by using 2 separate code bases, but I don't really want to do that unless I have to (I'll be creating more WPs and I don't want to have a separate project for each.
Is there something special I need to do to have multiple Web Parts in one project?
In config/config.json I have:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/config.2.0.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "bundles": {
    "webpart1": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/webparts/webpart1/WebPart1WebPart.js",
          "manifest": "./src/webparts/webpart1/WebPart1WebPart.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "webpart2": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/webparts/webpart2/WebPart2WebPart.js",
          "manifest": "./src/webparts/webpart2/WebPart2WebPart.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "externals": {},
  "localizedResources": {
    "WebPart1Strings": "lib/webparts/webpart1/loc/{locale}.js",
    "WebPart2Strings": "lib/webparts/webpart2/loc/{locale}.js",
    "ControlStrings": "node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
}

I'm not sure what else is relevant code-wise, but I can post anything needed.
If I look at https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js I can see the manifest for WebPart2, but not WebPart1.
Where do I start with this?  To create WebPart2 I copied and pasted WebPart1 - is there an ID or something that I need to change? I created a separate SettingsService for each part.

Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same.

No, sorry - I ended up just doing them separately, as far as I remember

I had the same problem.. I added 2 webparts to the same project.. The first webpart didnt give any problems, but when I added the second I could only see that.. That's why I found this..
After I wrote you I tested different things and weirdly enough I could not see the two first even when deleting the third.. Then i called the manifest.js directly and they were present all three.. When I updated the workbench I could see all three. It seemed to be a local cache that was refreshed when I called the manifest directly..
But I can see that didn't work for you.
